# Does Apache Calcite provide a way to add custom clauses or statements?

Tags: sql, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming, apache-calcite

I am currently working on a project to extend the functionalities of SQL to support more stream computing features based on Apache Flink.

After doing extensive search, I found that Calcite is a great tool to help me parse, validate and optimize those SQL queries, but the streaming support of Calcite is still immature so I have to improve it to suit my needs.

Hence, I would like to know if there is a way to add custom clauses like

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id   bigint,
    user varchar(20)
) PARAMS (
    connector 'kafka',
    topic     'my_topic'
)
```

which uses PARAMS to define how to receive data from a Kafka connector and treat it like a dynamic table as a data source to Flink.

Since there is so little information about this, I would greatly appreciate it if someone of you could provide some hints.

Thank you : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until the latest release (1.15.0, 11th Dec. 2017), Apache Calcite did not support DDL statements, such as `CREATE TABLE` or `DROP TABLE`. The reason was that

> SELECT and DML are standardized, but DDL tends to be
>   database-specific, so our policy is that you make DDL extensions
>   outside of Calcite.

(see [Calcite dev mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/c02f80366a08b555288bec043b3dcb75e0081aa27a385dbfbe726e52@%3Cdev.calcite.apache.org%3E)).

With Calcite 1.15.0, the community added [basic support for DDL statements](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-707). The feature was implemented as an optional module and shows how to customize DDL statements (see [documentation](http://calcite.apache.org/docs/adapter.html#server)). So, it is still expected that systems that use Calcite customize the parser and DDL syntax to their needs.

Comment: I looked at the calcite-server code and was not able to figure out if there is a way to get the SQL DDL Query from a Schema. Just to give you more context, I have created a schema and tables using some configuration file. Now, I was wondering if I can get the DDL for SQL table creation somehow.